# Cycle2 Responsive nested Slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, jquery-cycle2

I am trying to make a slideshow within a slideshow using Cycle2 http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/ and running into a few problems as I want the height of the slideshow's height to be dynamic and any content below it to be pushed down under it.

There are two tabs in the slideshow which reveal two slides, each containing 6 "products" with variable height. Here's an example of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Leta9/8/

Problems:

(1) The slideshow doesn't seem to initialise correctly. Once you click "Tab 1" and "Tab 2" a few times it corrects itself but as first (for me, in Chrome) I see the 2nd tab behind the 1st tab.

(2) The scrollHorz transition on the inner slider looks a bit funky, it isn't always contained in the red box as I'd want and overflows during transitions.

(3) The content below the slider is not being pushed below it. Before applying the outer slideshow (ie. without nesting) here http://jsfiddle.net/Leta9/7/ the responsive height is working ok as I've added `data-cycle-auto-height="container"` (see Dynamic Container Sizing docs - http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/container-resize.php ) and the content below stays below as I want.

I am also using Foundation 3 on the website this is on so there are some extra CSS styles to do with columns which I've mimicked on the fiddle but I don't see why this would be affecting things.

Have literally been struggling on this for hours, would appreciate some help SO much. Thank you!

HTML:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<div id="featured-slider ">
    <div id="per-slide-template" class="slider-tabs"></div>

    <div class="cycle-slideshow outer-slideshow" id="outer-slideshow"
        data-cycle-fx="fade"
        data-cycle-timeout="0"
        data-cycle-slides="> div"
        data-cycle-pager="#per-slide-template"
        data-cycle-speed="10"
        >


        <!-- TAB 1 CONTENTS-->
        <div class="product-slider" data-cycle-pager-template="<div class='tab-container'><a href=#>Tab 1</a></div>">
            <div class="nav prev one column">
                <a id="prev-1">Prev</a>
            </div>

            <div class="cycle-slideshow inner-slideshow ten columns"
                data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" 
                data-cycle-timeout="0" 
                data-cycle-prev="#prev-1" 
                data-cycle-next="#next-1" 
                data-cycle-swipe=true
                data-cycle-slides="> ul"
                data-cycle-speed="800"
                data-cycle-auto-height="container"
                >

                <ul class="product-slide twelve columns" id="product-slide-1-1">

                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x150" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x150" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x150" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x150" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x150" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x150" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>

                </ul>

                <ul class="product-slide twelve columns" id="product-slide-1-2">

                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x250" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x250" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x250" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x250" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x250" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x250" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div> 

            <div class="nav next one column">
                <a id="next-1">Next</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!--product-slider-->
        <!-- END TAB 1 CONTENTS-->
        <!-- TAB 2 CONTENTS-->
        <div class="product-slider" data-cycle-pager-template="<div class='tab-container'><a href=#>Tab 2</a></div>">
            <div class="nav prev one column">
                <a id="prev-2">Prev</a>
            </div>

            <div class="cycle-slideshow inner-slideshow ten columns"
                data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" 
                data-cycle-timeout="0" 
                data-cycle-prev="#prev-2" 
                data-cycle-next="#next-2" 
                data-cycle-swipe=true
                data-cycle-slides="> ul"
                data-cycle-speed="800"
                data-cycle-auto-height="container"
                >

                <ul class="product-slide twelve columns" id="product-slide-2-1">

                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x300" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x300" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x300" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x300" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x300" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x300" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>

                </ul>

                <ul class="product-slide twelve columns" id="product-slide-2-2">

                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x250" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x250" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x250" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x250" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x250" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="two columns product">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x250" /><span>Hello</span>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div> 

            <div class="nav next one column">
                <a id="next-2">Next</a>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!--product-slider-->
        <!-- END TAB 2 CONTENTS-->
    </div><!--outer-slideshow-->
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one {
    width: 8.3333%;
}

.two {
    width: 16.6666667%;
}

.ten {
    width: 83.33333%;
}

.twelve {
    width: 100%
}

.columns, .column {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 9px;
}


#featured-slider {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

.product-slider {
    border: 1px solid red;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

ul, li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
```